# Android : set FragmentActivity in full screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

I found many ways to show activity in full screen, but when i try it in FragmentActivity is not working !!
is there any possibility to show FragmentActivity in Full Screen ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Update your manifest file and add Theme as follows

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add to manifest of your activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

## To Remove TitleBar(Action bar)

use this in oncrete but before setcontentview(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

## To Remove status bar

use this in oncrete but before setcontentview(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well all you have to do is set flags for it as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in onCreate

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
```